# Python (Raspberry PI) motor library, AttributeError

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

I am getting this error (AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'getMotorLOC').
I am new to python and kinda stuk...
I am working on a motor library for a robot car with a raspberry pi in it.

Full error message:

```
runfile('C:/Users/Isaak/Documents/School DBH/GIP Project/GIP-Rover/Software/MotorLibrary/motorLib.py', wdir='C:/Users/Isaak/Documents/School DBH/GIP Project/GIP-Rover/Software/MotorLibrary')
Reloaded modules: jupyter_client.session, zmq.eventloop, zmq.eventloop.ioloop, tornado.platform, tornado.platform.asyncio, tornado.gen, zmq.eventloop.zmqstream, jupyter_client.jsonutil, jupyter_client.adapter, spyder, spyder.pil_patch, PIL, PIL._version, PIL.Image, PIL.ImageMode, PIL.TiffTags, PIL._binary, PIL._util, PIL._imaging, cffi, cffi.api, cffi.lock, cffi.error, cffi.model
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Isaak\Documents\School DBH\GIP Project\GIP-Rover\Software\MotorLibrary\motorLib.py", line 144, in <module>
    setupMotors("motor2", "motor3", "motor4", "motor1")

  File "C:\Users\Isaak\Documents\School DBH\GIP Project\GIP-Rover\Software\MotorLibrary\motorLib.py", line 71, in setupMotors
    Mlist = motor_loc(obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4)

  File "C:\Users\Isaak\Documents\School DBH\GIP Project\GIP-Rover\Software\MotorLibrary\motorLib.py", line 58, in motor_loc
    temp = OBJ_list[x].getMotorLOC()

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'getMotorLOC'
```

Short code explanation:
My idea is that you create 4 motor objects, give them the pins (IN1, IN2, EN) and the possition were they are on the car `LF = Left Front, RB = Right Back, etc.` 
so the code knows which motor to drive in which direction when for example, you say it has to go forward.
In the setup you repeat there names (so the all functions that will be using the library know the object names).
And you would be able to stere the car with only one line of code... (direction and speed)

Code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue May 11 18:57:42 2021

@author: Isaak

Motor Lib

"""
#import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

#GPIO.setwarnings(False)
#GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

Mlist = ["", "", "", ""]

class motor:  # this class is used to make the individual motor objects and to simplify the movement of it

    def __init__(self, EN, IN1, IN2, LOC):
        self.EN = EN
        self.IN1 = IN1
        self.IN2 = IN2
        self.LOC = LOC

    def Move(self, direction, speed=0):
        if 0 <= speed <= 100 and -1 <= direction <= 1:
            if direction == 1:
                print("Forward")
                #GPIO.output(self.IN1, GPIO.HIGH)
                #GPIO.output(self.IN2, GPIO.LOW)
                #GPIO.output(self.EN, GPIO.HIGH)
            elif direction == -1:
                print("Backwards")
                #GPIO.output(self.IN1, GPIO.LOW)
                #GPIO.output(self.IN2, GPIO.HIGH)
                #GPIO.output(self.EN, GPIO.HIGH)
            elif direction == 0:
                print("Stop")
                #GPIO.output(self.IN1, GPIO.LOW)
                #GPIO.output(self.IN2, GPIO.LOW)
                #GPIO.output(self.EN, GPIO.LOW)

    def getMotorLOC(self):
        return self.LOC
    
    def SetupMotor(self):
        pass
        #GPIO.setup(self.IN1, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.LOW)
        #GPIO.setup(self.IN2, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.LOW)
        #GPIO.setup(self.EN, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.LOW)


def motor_loc(Mo1, Mo2, Mo3, Mo4):
    OBJ_list = [Mo1, Mo2, Mo3, Mo4]
    M_list = ["", "", "", ""]
    for x in range(4):
        temp = OBJ_list[x].getMotorLOC()
        if temp == "LF":
            M_list[0] = OBJ_list[x]
        elif temp == "LB":
            M_list[1] = OBJ_list[x]
        elif temp == "RF":
            M_list[2] = OBJ_list[x]
        elif temp == "RB":
            M_list[3] = OBJ_list[x]
    return M_list


def setupMotors(obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4):
    Mlist = motor_loc(obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4)
    M1 = Mlist[0]
    M2 = Mlist[1]
    M3 = Mlist[2]
    M4 = Mlist[3]
    M1.SetupMotor()
    M2.SetupMotor()
    M3.SetupMotor()
    M4.SetupMotor()

def _4wd(Dir, speed):
    directionList = Dir.split()
    
    def motors_move(dirLF, dirLB, dirRF, dirRB, speed):
        M1 = Mlist[0]
        M2 = Mlist[1]
        M3 = Mlist[2]
        M4 = Mlist[3]
        M1.Move(dirLF, speed)
        M2.Move(dirLB, speed)
        M3.Move(dirRF, speed)
        M4.Move(dirRB, speed)

            
    def move(direction, speed):
        if direction == "stop" or direction == 0:
            motors_move(0, 0, 0, 0, speed)
        elif direction == "forward" or direction == 1:
            motors_move(1, 1, 1, 1, speed)
        elif direction == "backward" or direction == 2:
            motors_move(-1, -1, -1, -1, speed)
        elif direction == "left" or direction == 3:
            motors_move(-1, 1, 1, -1, speed)
        elif direction == "right" or direction == 4:
            motors_move(1, -1, -1, 1, speed)
        elif direction == "diagonalLF" or direction == 5:
            motors_move(1, 0, 0, 1, speed)
        elif direction == "diagonalLB" or direction == 6:
            motors_move(0, -1, -1, 0, speed)
        elif direction == "diagonalRF" or direction == 7:
            motors_move(0, 1, 1, 0, speed)
        elif direction == "diagonalRB" or direction == 8:
            motors_move(-1, 0, 0, -1, speed)

    def rotate(direction, speed):
        if direction == "left" or direction == 1:
            motors_move(-1, -1, 1, 1, speed)
        elif direction == "right" or direction == 2:
            motors_move(1, 1,  -1, -1, speed)
        elif direction == "FRotLF" or direction == 3:
            pass
        elif direction == "FRotLB" or direction == 4:
            pass
        elif direction == "FRotRF" or direction == 5:
            pass
        elif direction == "FRotRB" or direction == 6:
            pass
        
    if directionList[0] == "move":
        move(directionList[1], speed)
    elif directionList[0] == "rotate":
        rotate(directionList[1], speed)

#underneath is the usage off the library  (for now its just in the code)

motor2 = motor(32, 38, 36, "RF")
motor3 = motor(33, 29, 31, "LF")
motor4 = motor(12, 18, 16, "RB")
motor1 = motor(35, 40, 37, "LB")

setupMotors("motor2", "motor3", "motor4", "motor1")

while True:
    _4wd("move forward", 10)
    time.sleep(2)
    _4wd("move backward", 10)
    time.sleep(2)
```

RPI.GPIO is commented out (for testing).

Isaak

**EDIT**:
Error when `setupMotors(motor2, motor3, motor4, motor1)`

```
runfile('C:/Users/Isaak/Documents/School DBH/GIP Project/GIP-Rover/Software/MotorLibrary/motorLib.py', wdir='C:/Users/Isaak/Documents/School DBH/GIP Project/GIP-Rover/Software/MotorLibrary')
Reloaded modules: jupyter_client.session, zmq.eventloop, zmq.eventloop.ioloop, tornado.platform, tornado.platform.asyncio, tornado.gen, zmq.eventloop.zmqstream, jupyter_client.jsonutil, jupyter_client.adapter, spyder, spyder.pil_patch, PIL, PIL._version, PIL.Image, PIL.ImageMode, PIL.TiffTags, PIL._binary, PIL._util, PIL._imaging, cffi, cffi.api, cffi.lock, cffi.error, cffi.model
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Isaak\Documents\School DBH\GIP Project\GIP-Rover\Software\MotorLibrary\motorLib.py", line 147, in <module>
    _4wd("move forward", 10)

  File "C:\Users\Isaak\Documents\School DBH\GIP Project\GIP-Rover\Software\MotorLibrary\motorLib.py", line 130, in _4wd
    move(directionList[1], speed)

  File "C:\Users\Isaak\Documents\School DBH\GIP Project\GIP-Rover\Software\MotorLibrary\motorLib.py", line 99, in move
    motors_move(1, 1, 1, 1, speed)

  File "C:\Users\Isaak\Documents\School DBH\GIP Project\GIP-Rover\Software\MotorLibrary\motorLib.py", line 89, in motors_move
    M1.Move(dirLF, speed)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'Move'
```

Comment: If `OBJ_list[x]` is `"motor2"` rather than `motor2`, then `OBJ_list[x].getMotorLOC()` means `"motor2".getMotorLOC()`, not `motor2.getMotorLOC()`

Comment: "Move" is not the same as "move."  Look closely.

Comment: Yes, but ```Move``` is from the class move to move a motor and ```move``` is the list of available directions... and in this case you want to move the motor no select a direction...

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
setupMotors("motor2", "motor3", "motor4", "motor1")
```

to this

```
setupMotors(motor2, motor3, motor4, motor1)
```

Comment: It doesn't work (i had already tried it), but if you do it like that you are passing empty variables to the class... that function needs the names of the objects so they have to be surrounded by " "...

Comment: No, you are passing `motor` class object to `setupMotors` function.

Comment: What error are you getting? share that in the question because you definitely cannot pass string to that function.

Comment: Ok, so I made an edit in the original post, containing the error message when: ```setupMotors(motor2, motor3, motor4, motor1)```

Comment: Ok, that issue is solved, other function is causing issue. Now check `_4wd` function arguments

Comment: Pass proper arguments to function. Read docs if available for that code.

Comment: docs for that code? its mine, I wrote all of it... there are no docs lol

Comment: Then how could you mess up so bad 

Comment: I have no idea, it worked fine for a while... but its the first python code i wrote... (comming form C++) never done classes... lol